# Creating dynamic arrays from an existing array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i am trying to create new array from an existing. So basically i have an array that has the structure as shown below. How can i make it so that if i was to add a new object, that would result a new array from that point onwards?

```js
myArray: [{
    animal: 'cat',
    food: 'cupcake'
  },
  {
    animal: 'dog',
    food: 'pizza'
  },
  {
    animal: 'lion',
    food: 'apple'
  },
  {
    animal: 'elephant',
    food: 'spinach'
  },
]
```

So if i was to add a new Object `{ animal: 'rhino', food: 'banana'}` that result would in a new Array so it would be something like:

```
newArray: [
   { animal: 'rhino', food: 'banana' }
  ]
```

and if i was to add new object in the original array, that would end up in the new Array. Hopefully i have explained it to the best of my abilities.

Comment: Is your concern about mutating the original array?

Comment: @Nick Yeah, changing the state of original array.

Comment: Gotcha. The spread solution below should take care of it for you

Comment: This question is still very unclear. You supposedly want to add a new object to an array, but actually you want to create a new array? So... what's stopping you from creating a new array to begin with? What's the context?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I 100% agree with that. It was definitely not the right approach i was taking. Thanks for the help everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the spread operator for easily creating non-referencing arrays from existing ones.

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3] //original array
const myArray2 = [...myArray] //spread operator to create non-referencing array
myArray2.push(4)
console.log(myArray) // [1, 2, 3]
console.log(myArray2) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks Arc, I now understand how spread operators work :) Your comment was extremely clear. Thanks again.

Comment: My bad, didn't even realize. Be sure to check out spread operators for objects as well! And the MDN has some great overviews of use.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: I gave a similar answer, but have since deleted it because it seems that this is not what the OP is after.